# How to disable/grey-out the entire grid apart from top blank row and checkbox model when check box is selected in ExtJS 4.1.3

Tags: gridview, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a `Grid` with checkbox selection model, as soon as I select any check box a blank row is added on top of grid and below the header row. I want to disable/grey-out the entire grid apart from top blank row (1st row) and checkbox model (1st column) when `checkbox` is selected. 
I have tried with `grid.disable(true)` but it disables the entire grid.

How to restrict the 1st row and 1st column?

**Here is my code:**

```
var mystore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: datastore.fields,
    data: datastore.arrData
});

var sm = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
    mode: 'SIMPLE',
    checkOnly: true,
    renderer: function (v, p, record) {
        if (record.raw[record.raw.length - 1] == '')
            return '<div class="d-icon-right-list info-icon" >&nbsp;</div>';
        else
            return '<div class="x-grid-row-checker">&nbsp;</div>';
    },
    listeners: {
        selectionchange: function (sm, selected, eOpts) {
            listCB = selected;
            var gridID = Ext.getCmp('CiEditGrid');
            if (selected.length > 0) {
                gridID.getView().removeRowCls(0, 'hidden');
                gridID.getView().addRowCls(0, 'first_row');
            } else {
                gridID.getView().addRowCls(0, 'hidden');
            }
        },
        beforeselect: function (selModel, record, index) {
            var gridID = Ext.getCmp('CiEditGrid');
            popupIndex = index;
            if (!((ColumnIndex == undefined || ColumnIndex == 0)))
                return false;
        },
        beforedeselect: function (selModel, record, index) {
            if (!((ColumnIndex == undefined || ColumnIndex == 0) || (index == 0 && ColumnIndex != 0)))
                return false;
        }
    }
});

Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

var CiGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: mystore,
    border: false,
    columns: datastore.columns,
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    selModel: sm,
    id: 'CiEditGrid',
    height: 775,
    columnLines: true,
    enableColumnHide: false,
    viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function (record, rowIndex, rowParams, store, index) {
            if (listCB.length == 0 && rowIndex == 0 && record.raw[record.raw.length - 1] == '') {
                return "hidden";
            } else if (listCB.length != 0 && rowIndex == 0 && record.raw[record.raw.length - 1] == '')
                return "first_row";
        },
        forceFit: false,
        deferEmptyText: false,
        emptyText: '<div class="emptyTextClass">' + noRecordsFoundMsg + '</div>'
    },
    lockedViewConfig: {
        emptyText: ''
    },
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (grid, eOpts) {
            var gridIndxArray = grid.columns;
            for (var i = 0; i < gridIndxArray.length; i++) {
                var Indx = i - 1;
                if (Indx == -1)
                    Indx = 0;
                ColumnIndexArray.push({
                    dataIndx: gridIndxArray[i].dataIndex,
                    StoreIndx: Indx
                });
            }
            lastDataIndex = ColumnIndexArray[ColumnIndexArray.length - 1].dataIndx;
        },
        columnmove: function (ct, column, fromIdx, toIdx) {
            isColumnreconfigured = true;
        },
        itemmouseenter(grid, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
            if (index == 0)
                Ext.fly(item).set({
                    'data-qtip': MultiEditRowTooltip
                });
        },
        sortchange(ct, column, direction, eOpts) {
            console.log(column, ct);
        },
        itemclick: function (data, record, item, index, e, eOpts) { // data,td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex,e,eOpts 
            popupIndex = index;
            var position = data.getPositionByEvent(e);
            ColumnIndex = position.column;
            RowIndex = position.row;
            if (index == 0) {
                multiCol.push({
                    colIndex: ColumnIndex
                });
            }
            EditedValues.push({
                colvalue: ColumnIndex,
                rowvalue: popupIndex
            });
            if (isColumnreconfigured) {
                for (var i = 0; i < ColumnIndexArray.length; i++) {
                    if (this.getView().getGridColumns()[ColumnIndex + 2].dataIndex == ColumnIndexArray[i].dataIndx) {
                        ColumnIndex = ColumnIndexArray[i].StoreIndx;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            var colHeader = this.columns[ColumnIndex + 1];
            if ((typeof (colHeader.editor) != 'undefined' && colHeader.editor.xtype == 'textareafield') || (typeof (colHeader.field) != 'undefined' && colHeader.field.xtype == 'textareafield')) {
                var header = colHeader.text;
                var dataindex = colHeader.dataIndex;
                var isReadonly = colHeader.isReadonly;
                maxLengthForPopup = colHeader.length;
                dataIndexForPopup = dataindex;
                var old = this.getStore().data.getAt(index).get(dataindex);
                showExpansionWindow(record, old, header, maxLengthForPopup, isReadonly);
            }
        }
    },
    cls: 'custom-dirty',
    layout: 'fit',
    border: false,
    autoWidth: true,
    plugins: [cellEditing],
    renderTo: 'grid'
});
```

Comment: Provide a code showing your work and describe specifically, what and where is the problem.

Comment: @MarthyM added the code, here I have added CB model and a specially styled row is added when any of the CB is selected.
Now I want to disable the entire grid as soon as any checkbox is selected, but only CB selection column and the specially styled row should be editable.